# BigQuery - Updating a rows Partiton Timestamp Value, does this repartition

Tags: google-bigquery

If I am inserting rows into BQ, using a custom partiton column, the rows are placed in the right date partition.  Great.

If I subsequently issue a DML Update statement to a bunch of row, updating the timestamp value of the column used for partitioning, will these rows be re-partitioned based on the new value just update to?  Essentially 'moving' its partition?

Thanks

Comment: it should! have you tried?

Comment: Thanks Mikhail yes it does :)  Just wanted to double check as it wasnt explicitly stated in the doco (maybe I missed that though haha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does

Even more - using an UPDATE statement you can modify the `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo column